# How to add values to uipickerview from database sqlite?

Tags: uipickerview

Am new to sqlite and also programming,
Am trying this from a week and not able to move a bit forward.I have seen U have helped many and I think I can be solved my problem by you.I have posted a lot,but I didnt get any reply from any where for this .
U can contact me : smrafiqsmd@gmail.com

At first I have to create two separate uipickerviews on same view.In that pickerview I have to insert values from sqlite database tables.
In first view i have to get the values from first table of sqlite.And in second view i have to get the values from second table by comparing with the id.
the views must be on same view.

Table1:qualification

CREATE TABLE qualification ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(50), description TEXT);

INSERT INTO "qualification" VALUES(1,'P.G','Post Graduation');

INSERT INTO "qualification" VALUES(1,'Degree','Under Graduation');

INSERT INTO "qualification" VALUES(1,'Ten+Two','college');

Table2:course

CREATE TABLE Course (Id Integer primarykey,number integer,name1 varchar(20),description1 Text(30));

INSERT INTO "Course" VALUES(1,1,'MCA','Master in computers');
INSERT INTO "Course" VALUES(2,1,'MBA','Master in Bussiness');
INSERT INTO "Course" VALUES(3,2,'BSc','Bachelor in sscience');
INSERT INTO "Course" VALUES(4,2,'BCom','Bachelor in accounts');
INSERT INTO "Course" VALUES(5,3,'MPC','Mathematics');
INSERT INTO "Course" VALUES(5,3,'BPC','Biology');

See in first table i will get values P.G,Degree,Ten+
Two

when i click on P.G it must display in textfield and in second pickerview I must get values only which matches with
"id" of qualification with
"number " of course.

And when we select value it must display in textfield
Thank u

Answer (score 0):

I have made a project to show you how to do what you are asking for.

You can download the project from here:

http://www.crowsoft.com.ar/downloads/twoPickerViews.zip

A very good tutorial for sqlite in iPhone could be found here:

http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-1/

To manage a PickerView you need an array to hold the data.

I have declared two classes (Qualification and Course) to represent your tables and two NSMutableArray variables to hold the data.

To link the two PickerViews you need to implement UIPickerViewDataSource and UIPickerViewDelegate in your view controler:

```
@interface twoPickerViewsViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate> {
```

to respond when the user select a qualification you need to code didSelectRow:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
   // And now the final part of the UIPickerView, what happens when a row is selected.
   if (thePickerView == qualificationsPicker) {
       if (row >= 0 && row < [m_qualifications count]) {
           m_selectedQualification = [m_qualifications objectAtIndex:row];    
           qualificationName.text = m_selectedQualification.qualificationName;
           [self getCourses];
           [coursesPicker reloadAllComponents];
       }
   }
}
```

You need to code three more methods, numberOfComponentsInPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent, titleForRow:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView {
   // This method needs to be used. It asks how many columns will be used in the UIPickerView
   return 1; // We only need one column so we will return 1.
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
   // This method also needs to be used. This asks how many rows the UIPickerView will have.
   if (thePickerView == qualificationsPicker) {
       return [m_qualifications count]; // We will need the amount of rows that we used in the pickerViewArray, so we will return the count of the array.
   }
   else {
       return [self getCourses];
   }
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
   // This method asks for what the title or label of each row will be.
   if (thePickerView == qualificationsPicker) {
       Qualification *qualification = [m_qualifications objectAtIndex:row];
       return qualification.qualificationName; // We will set a new row for every string used in the array.
   }
   else {
       Course *course = [m_selectedCourses objectAtIndex:row];
       return course.courseName;
   }    
}
```